# Question on Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Given $a = [-5, 8, 1]$ and  $b = [2, -7, -3]$, find a vector $c$ such that $a \cdot (b × c) = 0$

I don't know how to get it, I've been looking for examples, but I don't know..

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: Since they are coplanar, I tried using numbers out of my head so that the volume is 0. But I don't really know a procedure that could help me.

Comment: A brute force approach could be to set $c= (c_1,c_2,c_3)$ insert that in the condition $a\cdot(b \times c)=0$ and solve the associated linear system.

Comment: But, that is going to give me 3 unknown values, I can't simplify them. Can I?

Comment: yes you can, then your system is overdetermined but should have solution**s** (there is a probably a more elegant solution).

Comment: What happens if my c coordinates are [0,0,0]?

Comment: Then the equality is true, but there may be other (more interesting) solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like anything in the span of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ so anything of the form:

$$\mathbb{c}=k\, \mathbf{a}+\lambda\, \mathbf{b},$$
for scalars $k$ and $\lambda$.

If you draw a picture, you will see that in this case $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are all in the same plane and so $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}$ will be perpendicular to the plane and particular to $\mathbf{a}$.

Also, algebraically,

$$\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{b}\times (k\,\mathbf{a}+\lambda \,\mathbf{b})=k\,\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{a}+\lambda\,\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{b}=k\,\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{a},$$

and now

$$\mathbf{a}\cdot (\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c})=\mathbf{a}\cdot (k\,\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{a})=k\,(\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{a}))=0.$$

Comment: What does k and λ stand for?

Comment: @Julio scalars... just any real numbers at all.

Comment: So they can be 1 and 2?

Comment: @Julio what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Let c=(0,0,0). Not probably what you meant...

Comment: Is that possible? A vector needs magnitude...

Comment: @Julio well, this vector has magnitude zero... so it does have magnitude.